# Error TS5023: Unknown compiler option '--build'

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, tsc, winston-elasticsearch

I have been using typescript in my node project. Initially when I run **`tsc --build`** it runs correctly and builds my project but after installing a package **`winston-elasticsearch`** the error starts occuring while running **`tsc --build`**.

Error:

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option '--build'.
```

**Versions**

```
Typescript version => 5.0.4
Node version => 12.22.12
winston-elasticsearch => 0.16.1
winston => 3.7.2
```

I tried installing other version of **`winston-elasticsearch`** but still same error persists.

`tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": ["./src/typings", "../../node_modules/@types", "./src/common"],
    "types": ["reflect-metadata", "jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "src/**/*.test.*", "node_modules", "src/admin/ui/**/*"]
}
```